# What value will var_dump show that echo will not show? (Only one word answer)

Tags: php, var-dump

I was solving a question and got to see this one. I really don't know what it is. Just needed a one word answer for the problem.

Comment: **DataTypes** (but I have to use more words than that to get a comment or an answer to post :) )

Comment: Or you could simply ___Do one___ to compare it with an `echo`

Comment: [Mixed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.mixed) (Which means pretty much everything, including nulls, objects, arrays, functions, etc) Where as echo can only show strings.

Answer (score 2):

**A variable type.**

Expanded answer:
Even a line number if you have XDebug activated.

Also,

- you won't see empty strings or falses using echo.
- echo() doesn't show something except strings and types that can be converted to strings (like int, float, boolean or objects having __toString magic method).